# Digitally controlled potentiometer X9C103P gives erratic resistance measurements

Tags: potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I have a digitally controlled potentiometer (DCP) X9C103P ([datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/x9c102-103-104-503.pdf)) which I am trying to operate. Following are the pin connections I've made refering to its datasheet:

Pin 1: INC (resistance increment/decrement) - connected to programmatically controlled digital output port of a I2C device ([NI-8451](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/model.usb-8451.html))

Pin 2: U/D (resistance change up/down)- tied to Vcc

Pin 3: VH (Pot end terminal 1) - floating

Pin 4: Vss - grounded

Pin 5: VW (Pot wiper terminal) - floating

Pin 6: VL (Pot end terminal 2) - floating OR grounded

Pin 7: CS (pot enable) - tied to ground

Pin 8: Vcc - +5V

The pot resistance is incremeneted when the INC terminal is given a trailing edge (clocked from high to low), and I am doing that programatically using a DIO port controlled by LabVIEW. However, when I measure the resistance between VH and VW, the measurement at times comes out to be 20 Ohms and at times >100 kOhms or even a NO CONNECT (NC). I even checked the voltage on the Vcc and Vss pins to check whether there was a lose connection (since I am using a breadboard), but all the pins gave me the expected voltage.

Upon clocking the INC terminal too, this problem persists i.e., the resistance between VH and VW is either 20 Ohms or an NC. What is also worrisome is that the resistance should increment after clocking, which isn't happening. I contacted the manufacturer and he has suggested me to tie the VL pin to ground and repeat the procedure. I did that but it still is giving me the same error.

Hence, can anyone help me with resolving this issue?

Comment: I would suggest adding a schematic, even a hand drawn one would be fine, but not a frizzy thing. From the data sheet and your description it is not connected properly. The pot side must have both Vih and Vil connected to a voltage source.